# Google map doesn't show when i use 'push' segue for transition in swift. How can i resolve it?

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have various viewcontrollers in swift, one of them contains a google map, when I use the 'push' segue for transition, the google map doesn't appear. How can I resolve it?

Comment: We need more information, show some code. Do you get any errors at all? If so, what are they? Read this sscce.org

Comment: when i use "modal" for segue, the map shows perfectly. The problem is when i use 'push' as segue, the map doesn't appear

Comment: i don't have errors, only it doesn't show the google map

Comment: i resolved it, i only created a custom segue in another class. Thank's for all

Comment: You can answer your own question, just post your comment as an answer (preferably with some more information to help those who look at this question later)

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it, i only created a custom segue in another class. Thank's for all